How can I save an alias macro to a register?
In Doom Emacs, I can record a macro with evil-record-macro in register a and then easily replay it multiple times with 10@a. This works well, but I’d like a way to make macros persistent across Emacs restarts, using names I can access later.
Here’s my current approach:

Record a macro with evil-record-macro as I have described.

Run name-last-kbd-macro to name the recorded macro (though it won’t persist after restart).

Run insert-kbd-macro to generate a persistent definition and then save it in my config.el file, e.g.,
(defalias 'z/my-macro (kmacro "<return> SPC m m F u q h j"))



This lets me reuse z/my-macro after restarting Emacs, but I lose the ability to repeat it with a prefix count, like 10@a. To solve that problem, I tried placing it back in a register with:
(set-register ?a (cons 'macro (symbol-function 'z/my-macro)))

but it didn’t work as expected, I can't put z/my-macro inside the a register like that. Is there a way to store a named macro in a register for repeated execution? or is there a simpler solution to make macros both persistent and easily repeatable after restarting Emacs?

C-u 10 M-x z/my-macro would repeat it 10 times.  Or M-1 M-0 M-x ..., or your preferred way of supplying a numeric prefix argument.

You should add evil tag(s) to your question if you are specifically asking how to make it repeatable using evil's keys.  (I don't use evil, so I don't know the answer to that.)

I would check the code to see exactly what evil-record-macro does with registers, though.  The following wouldn't normally be very useful, but evil might just be doing: (set-register ?a (kmacro "<return> SPC m m F u q h j"))

According to the GNU documentation, you can use kmacro-to-register to store the last recorded macro in a register. Default keybinding is C-x C-k x r to store in register r.
